# Reactjs old work is rendering to the browser, new code having no impact in browser

Tags: reactjs

I was working on a React application that I had to not work on for awhile.

I came back to it. I start up my local server using `live-server public/`

and no matter what I do on my `app.js` file, nothing renders. I can still see the last work I did on the browser, but my `app.js` file is having no impact in the browser even though what is rendering on the browser is from my `app.js` file. Honestly, I can never get used to this silent failure on the part of React. All the files are loading properly.

What should I be looking for? What am I missing?

This is my `app.js` file:

```
console.log('App.js is running');

const app = {
  title: 'Decision',
  subtitle: 'For binary life decisions, put your trust in a computer',
  options: []
};

const onFormSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const option = e.target.elements.option.value;

  if (option) {
    app.options.push(option);
    e.target.elements.option.value = '';
    render();
  }
};

const onRemoveAll = () => {
  app.options = [];
  render();
};
// create "Remove All" button above list
// on click -> wipe the array -> rerender

const appRoot = document.getElementById('app');

const numbers = [55, 101, 1000];

const render = () => {
  const template = (
    <div>
      <h1>{app.title}</h1>
      {app.subtitle && <p>{app.subtitle}</p>}
      <p>{app.options.length > 0 ? 'Here are your options' : 'No options'}</p>
      <p>{app.options.length}</p>
      <button onClick={onRemoveAll}>Remove All</button>
      {
        [99, 98, 97]
      }
      <ol>
        <li>Item one</li>
        <li>Item two</li>
      </ol>
      <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="option" />
        <button>Add Option</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );

  ReactDOM.render(template, appRoot);
};

render();
```

Comment: can you show `app.js` file? do you run webpack, after doing changes in `app.js` file?

Comment: The code seems confusing to me. When I look at the code I see lots of method that can call `render` which does this as the last step `ReactDOM.render(template, appRoot);` But `ReactDOM.render` should only be applied once. This looks like you are trying to use state handling in an alternative way. Why not use `class component` and `setState` ?

Comment: @Kunukn, thank you for the feedback. Could this be the cause of the reason why nothing I do renders?

Comment: @Ale, did you use `yarn` or did you use `npm`?

Comment: @Daniel, I think I used both because I was having problems with `yarn` when installing the `live-server`.

Comment: @Ale, you need to pick one. I would recommend sticking with `npm` and perhaps you may need to redo everything, meaning install `live-server`, `babel`, `babel-presets`, `babel-env`. Do all that with `npm`. I say that because it sounds like the issue is your code is not compiling for it to render in the browser.

Comment: @Daniel, now my work in `app.js` is rendering to the browser and any additional work I do to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was your application was not transpiling, so you were not seeing any changes made in your code render in the browser. This also explains why you were seeing only what you last worked on.

You were using `yarn` for one thing and then using `npm` install for something else. If `yarn` installations are not working for you, you can start using `npm`, but once you do, stick with it.

Redo the `package.json` installation except do it with `npm`.

Run `npm init`

Reinstall with `npm install babel-preset-react babel-preset-env live-server`

You should be able to see all the changes you make to your `app.js` file render now.